# SSRS subscription - change the date format (@ExecutionTime) on the subject line

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, subscription

**Problem**: The default subject line in an SSRS subscription email uses the @ExecutionTime pre-defined variable and at runtime replaces the same with a datetime in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss format.  Since, we have deployed our product for an Indian client, we would like the date format in dd/mm/yyyy format.

Most of the posts on the internet have suggested using data-driven report subscription to construct a custom email subject.  But as per SQL Server documentation, this feature is available in Enterprise and BI editions only.

Other attempts to use =Parameters!ExecutionDateTime **or** =FORMAT(@ExecutionTime,"dd-MMM-yyyy") **or** =format(Globals!ExecutionTime , "MMM yyyy") have failed.

Two days of futile attempts in solving this.  Will continue looking, and hope the SO community can help.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by Tushar Sood, I would like to add that: the language **can be** made to work for subscriptions added **after changing** the language settings.

This can be achieved by doing the following steps in the reporting database:

1. Go to the SQL server which is hosting your Reporting Services
2. Open the SQL Server Management studio and go to a database called *"ReportServer"*
3. Expand database *"Reportserver"*
4. Expand Tables
5. Open the table called *"dbo.Subscriptions"* in Edit Mode...You will see a column called *"Locale"*

For some reports which is showing *"M/d/yyyy"* format the locale will be set to value *"en-US".*

6. Change the value to *"en-GB"*

Now all your reports **(including old ones**) using *@ExecutionTime* will start showing date time in *"en-GB"* format.

That's it... Happy Reporting!!!

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable, but true.  The date format of the @ExecutionTime variable is determined by the Language setting on the Report Server's Internet Explorer.  Here's how you can change it:

1. In IE, open settings -> Internet Options -> Languages -> Add.. -> English (India) [en-IN]  (or the language with the date format that you require)
2. Now add a new SSRS subscription and verify the email received.

PS: This only works for subscriptions added after changing the language settings.  The earlier subscription emails will continue to use the earlier format.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! What I found on my system was that the locale of a new report subscription follows the default language in the browser of the user who sets up the subscription. In my case, in Chrome, my default language is English (UK), and the locale created in a new subscription is en-GB. Changing my default browser language to English (US) changes the locale created in a new subscription to en-US.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't touch a runing systems, what you do is really meaningless, hier is the right solution::

You can change the Format as you like within the report, first create Data Drive Subscription and put this statements inside
--TOP-------------------------------
DECLARE @Datum AS CHAR(10) SET @Datum = convert(char(10),getdate(),104)

IF object_id('tempdb..##Kommentar') is not null DROP TABLE ##Kommentar

SELECT 'Hi dear Silvia(#)
as you asked me last week, today I would like to send the report of ' + **@Datum** + ' to you (#) Have a nice day (#)(#) Best regards (#)(#) H.Labidi' AS Kommentar
INTO ##Kommentar --Global table

SELECT Kommentar from ##Kommentar
--DOWN-------------------------

IMPORTANT: at the "(#)" replace it with Html "CR"

and then at the Body of the report email use the "Kommentar" as variable

that is!!!!

It works 100% for me!

RESOLVED by Habib Labidi

Comment: OP says they can't use data-driven report subscriptions.